# Exporting spritesheet for cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet

I would like to know how people usually save the animations in order to load them easily in Cocos2d with as few hard-code as possible.

E.G. The solution I thought of is to have one plist file containing information about each frame, and the second plist to contain information about each of the animation(name of the animation, which frames to play, and the delay probably).

If this is the correct solution, how can I generate such plist files for spritesheet automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a texture packer tool in order to create a sprite atlas and the corresponding plist. `Zwoptex` works pretty well for me. Once you have your png and plist, you can load them with
`SpriteFrameCache`

`[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"gameSprites.plist"];`

Also, you may use a naming convention for your animation frames, for instance suffixing them with '_index': `animFrame_1`, `animFrame_2`, and so on...

Then you can have a CCAnimation category with helpers to load animations given an animation name and frame count. You can take next code as an example.-

```
+ (CCAnimation *) animationWithFrame:(NSString *) frame frameCount:(int) frameCount startIndex:(int) startIndex delay:(float) delay separator:(NSString *) separator {
    // load the ship's animation frames as textures and create a sprite frame
    NSMutableArray* frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frameCount];
    CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    int end = frameCount + startIndex;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < end; i++)
    {
        NSString* file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%i.png", frame, separator, i];
        CCSpriteFrame* frame = [frameCache spriteFrameByName:file];
        [frames addObject:frame];
    }
    // Return an animation object from all the sprite animation frames
    return [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:frames delay:delay];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and where can I get frameCount for certain animation? I think hard-coding it will be not efficient when I have many animations.. It would be much better to read that information from .plist to. 

Can e.g. Zwoptex store somewhere information about framecount for certain animations? probably generate secondary plist, or whatever the solution is then?

Comment: You're right, but sadly Zwoptex doesn't let you add that kind of metadata, I usually have a set of constants/enum to keep my animation frameCounts. LevelHelper features more control over animations info, but if you only need it for managing your animations frame counts, it'd probably not worthy. In that case, it would be faster to write your own plist mapping animation name-frame count.